# Throws NameError: name 'pathlib' is not defined with Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I was using pathlib module, for directory browsing. 
Here is the snippet i was trying.

```
import sys,os
from pathlib import Path

root = "C:\"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print(pathlib.PurePath(path, name))
```

I get the following exception: "NameError: name 'pathlib' is not defined"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You used `from .. import ...` statement instead of `import ..`.

Replacing following line:

```
from pathlib import Path
```

with:

```
import pathlib
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: Why can you not use `from ... import ...` in this case?

Comment: @GraysonPike, Because OP's code refer `pathlib` afterward: `pathlib.PurePath`. If you just use `PurePath`, you can use `from pathlib import Pathlib`.